# Using external string variable with Groovy Markup Builder

Tags: groovy, markupbuilder

I have created a string variable using some logic in groovy which reflects the braket syntax in markup builder but the problem is that you are obviously not allowed to use this string in markup  builder. The nature of my code makes it necessary. I want to know if there is a way of doing something like the following

```
def param = "node1{ node2{ node3() } }"
def sw = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)

XML = xml.param
```

I know the above code is not correct but is there a way of doing what i am driving at? To be clear param is a string which is the product of another piece of code. I am looking to get out a piece of XML like the following:

```
<node1><node2><node3/></node2><node1>
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't understand what do you want. Can you add more details. What do you have, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to have the script have an XMl ouput using the nodes contained in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your closure `string` to be (I've called it `builder` as I'm not keen on lower-cased class names as property names)

```
def builder = { ->
    node1 {
        node2{
            node3()
        }
    }
}
```

You can then do this with `StreamingMarkupBuilder`:

```
String output = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { 
    builder.delegate = delegate
    builder()
}.toString()
```

And `output` will contain the String:

```
<node1><node2><node3/></node2></node1>
```

#### Edit:

Looks like I misunderstood and the `param` variable is a String.  In that case, you can do this to evaluate the String (wrapped in a closure) and do much the same as above:

```
def param = "node1 { node2 { node3() } }"

String output = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { smb ->
    Eval.me( "{ -> $param }" ).with { c ->
        c.delegate = smb
        c()
    }
}.toString()
```

It should be noted however, that care must be taken when doing anything with Eval.  It won't care if the code is malicious, or benign, it will just run it, possibly crashing your app or deleting code or worse.

Maybe instead of building a String, you could build a map or something?  Then you could do something like this:

```
def param = [ node1:[ node2:[ node3:'' ] ] ]

String output = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    param.each { k, v ->
        "$k" { v instanceof Map ? v.each( owner ) : mkp.yield( v ) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi tim, thanks for your answer, just require a little bit more help. I had watered down my example quite a bit, the definition of the closure builder is not being done in one step instead it is the product of several if statements and loops. Is there any way of me using the parameter string in my original question as my start point then converting this to a closure and using in the way you have said?

Comment: sorry let me re word. You have the closure called builder. In my code i have this as a string after the product of several conditional statements and loops etc, is it possible to convert this string to a closure and then use the code you have given?

Comment: You mean `param` in your question should be a String?  You have it as the result of a method call in your question.

Comment: yes it is a string, i have tried to clarify the original question now, sorry. Is this possible?